# changing background in java scripts css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im very beginner in html and java scripts, I already have a webui which is running by angular, and I just want to add a button to be able change the background color. all of the code is by  
and I can't add any function, sorry about this question if it's so basic.

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div>
    <h2>
        Select project: <br>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" (ngModelChange)="onProjectChange($event)">
           <option [ngValue] = "project" *ngFor="let project of projects">{{project}}</option>
        </select>
    </h2>   
</div>
<div *ngIf="(!andon) && selectedProject" id="container">
    <hr>
    <h2>Device not connected.</h2> 
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the background color of the body or which element?

If you want to change the body background color you can use the following code:

```html
<app-header></app-header>

<div>
    <h2>
        Select project: <br>
        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedProject" (ngModelChange)="onProjectChange($event)">
           <option [ngValue] = "project" *ngFor="let project of projects">{{project}}</option>
        </select>
    </h2>   
</div>
<div *ngIf="(!andon) && selectedProject" id="container">
    <hr>
    <h2>Device not connected.</h2> 
</div>
<button type="button"  (click)="onChangeBackground()"
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {

  onChangeBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }

}
```

Still not sure if this is gonna be useful to you since you wrote you can't add any function.